# Enable bucket notifications for all users in Ceph Octopus

Tags: ceph

The question is how to configure bucket notifications to publish events from any user that made changes for a bucket? Or may be there is options to enable notification for entire ceph storage regardless of a bucket or a user?

TIA

Edit:
Will try to be a bit more specific - I have user "test1" that created bucket "bucket1", I configured bucket notification according to the official docs for bucket1 where endpoint is kafka. Now I can see events in the configured topic when I do any actions in the bucket by user1. After that I create a new user, lets say, user2. Throught bucket policy of the bucket1 I give user2 rights to put, delete objects in this bucket. However, when I do any action by user2 in the bucket "bucket1" I do not see any events in the previously configured topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it is a bug - https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/47904